# When does $AB$ have linearly independent columns, if $A$ and $B$ are non-square matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-rank

If

- $A$ is $m \times n$ ($m<n$), and its rows are independent
- $B$ is $n \times p$ ($p<n$), and its columns are independent
- We also know $m\ge n$.

does $AB$ have linearly independent columns?

Or what additional requirements are needed for $AB$ to have linearly independent columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ has rank $m$ and $B$ has rank $p$, $AB$ has rank at most $\min(m,p)$.
$AB$ is $m\times p$, so it could have linearly independent columns if $m \ge p$,
but not if $m < p$.

Comment: So it is possible that AB has linearly independent columns if $m\ge p$, but not always?

Comment: For an example with $m=p=2$ and $n=3$, try $A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr}$, $B = \pmatrix{0 & 0\cr 1 & 0\cr 0 & 1\cr}$.

Answer (score 0):

For this we need $AB $ to have rank $p $ (since $p$ columns). All we are garanteed however is that the rank of $AB$ is less orequal to the minimum of $\{m,n,p\}$. So this will fail for example when $m <p$.

Comment: what if we also know $m \ge p$

Comment: @Oliver Chang The columns should not  necessarily be independent. I'd try to find an example.

Comment: I guess it's actually quite easy to make the rows of A orthogonal to columns of B, if n is large.